# Does the event of big bang violates first law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-hole-thermodynamics

First law states that energy can neither be created nor be destroyed. So how did the big bang gathered so much energy to expode?

Comment: As soon as general relativity enters there is nothing like conservative of energy even after billions of years after big bang the dark energy gets added to universe from nowhere.